# Http proxy to connect with https website php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Is it possible to connect to an https website with an http proxy(which doesn't support https)?

I know the data will not be secure and all that, But is it possible anyway ?

I am using the following code, It works with `http://website.com` But doesn't work with the `https://website.com`

```
$proxy = "proxy which doesn't support https"
$url = "https://website.com" //https url
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Curl throws the following error when I try to connect to HTTP website `Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: HTTPS is "end to end", which means that the client speaks it *through* the proxy to the remote server. A normal HTTP proxy does not speak HTTPS, it just tunnels it through, back and forth.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I have tried this with many HTTP proxies, they work with HTTP website but when I try to connect to https website,  They don't work For ex. I just tried 220.100.130.121:8080  to connect to https://stackoverflow.com via curl  But get the error `Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: "normal" HTTP proxies support CONNECT requests fine at least to port 443. Your random open proxies on the internet might not though. That's not a curl problem, that's a use-a-sensibly-configured-proxy problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Curl can connect to http://eaxmple.com but while connecting https:example.com via proxy it throws error `Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`